# Is this good phraseology?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, phraseology

The passage below comes from an article published by BBC.
http://www.bbc.com/news/health-39292389

> Dr Thomas said: "**It could be to maintain health we need to be
>   exercising much more than we do."**

Am I correct in assuming that it would sound more elegant if you rewrote it as follows:

**It could be that we need to be exercising much more than we do to maintain health**.

Comment: Yes, you are indeed right.

Comment: Or a couple of commas might sort it out: "It could be, to maintain health, we need to be exercising much more than we do." Don't forget that this was a verbal comment, and much of what is spoken is composed on the fly in *thought order,* which may not make for felicity of expression.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, What  extra sense does this sentence construction make other than what "To maintain health we need to exercise more than we do" gives?

Comment: Simply adding _in order to_ in front of the infinitive _to maintain health_ will mark it as a purpose infinitive, which, like most adverb clauses, can go in several positions. The fact that the infinitive is not marked as any special kind of infinitive makes it unclear what the construction actually is.

Comment: The non-omission of 'that' would improve the sentence greatly, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, an even better way of putting it would be:

> It could be that to maintain health we need to be exercising much more
>   than we do.

Or:

> It could be that in order to maintain health we need to be exercising
>   much more than we do.